# Converting loop into a single line command to improve shell script performance in HP-UX

Tags: awk, ksh, hp-ux

I have the following loop in my shell script.  What it does is it removed the record which is more then 3000 bytes actually it taking longer time as it read and line by line check byte, and if less then 3000 bytes create a file.

```
if [ $FILE_NM = "HUN" ]
then
    HUN_FILENM=` ls HUN*.txt | tail -1 `
    while read line
    do
        bytes=` echo $line | wc -c `
        if (( $bytes <= 3000 )); then
            echo "$line" >> output290_donot_delete.txt
        fi
    done < $HUN_FILENM
    mv output290_donot_delete.txt $HUN_FILENM
fi
```

Is there any command in Unix which read file if less then 3000 bytes then create file. I need to avoid the loop

Comment: You also need to avoid the >> append inside the loop. That searches the directory, opens the file, seeks to end, reads last block, adds one line, writes last block, and closes the file, for every output line. Cache might save you something, but not enough. You need a `>` after the `done` instead. But `awk` is the right tool here -- typical speed-up factor 50 to 200.

Comment: Do you want to get the first 3000 bytes of the file, OR do you want to get all lines whose size is <= 3000 bytes? And do you really want bytes or do you want characters? For example, `ά` is 2 bytes, but one character.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 5):

```
while read line; do
    bytes=` echo $line | wc -c `
done
```

This is probably the slow part, you're running an external command for each input line.

In ksh, you could just use `${#line}` to get the length of the string in that variable. Though note that if you have multibyte characters, the shell might count one for each whole *character*, while `wc -c` counts one for each *byte*. Add `LC_ALL=C` to have the script use the C locale which should result in all individual bytes being counted.

However, the shell probably isn't the fastest or best tool to use for this. If I read your script right, you want to remove the lines that are longer than 3000 characters. You could do that with `grep` (this should be a standard BRE):

```
grep -e '^.\{0,300\}$' "$file"
```

or with awk:

```
awk 'length <= 3000' "$file"
```

Similarly, using the C locale should help here if you want to count bytes instead: `LC_ALL=C awk ...`.